# c# xml into datagrid different level of child

Tags: c#, xml, datagrid

I'm in need to work an xml like this

```
<jobpost id='01'>
    <candidate id='0000079'>
        <firstName>AAAA</firstName>
        <lastName>BBBB</lastName>
        <age>32</age>
        <salaryoff>37000</salaryoff>
        <exp>C</exp>
        <cat>
            <award>5</award>
            <hst>5</hst>
            <previous>7</previous>
            <flex>3</flex>
            <travel>4</travel>
        </cat>
    </candidate>
    <candidate id='0000072'>
        <firstName>CCCCC</firstName>
        <lastName>DDDDD</lastName>
        <age>37</age>
        <salaryoff>40000</salaryoff>
        <exp>B</exp>
        <cat>
            <award>6</award>
            <hst>5</hst>
            <previous>6</previous>
            <flex>2</flex>
            <travel>3</travel>
        </cat>
    </candidate>        
</jobpost>
```

and display in a datagrid in this format

```
name    last    age exp awa hst pre fle tra salaryoff

AAAA    BBBB    32  C   5   5   7   3   4   37000

CCCCC   DDDDD   37  B   6   5   6   2   3   40000
```

I've tried somthing like this

```
XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(my_path + "jobpost.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);
candidati.DataSource = dataSet;
candidati.DataMember = "cat";
xmlFile.Close();
```

but I only manage to have one part of info as I need

```
awa hst pre fle tra

5   5   7   3   4

6   5   6   2   3
```

or

```
candidati.DataMember = "candidate";


name    last    age exp salary  
AAAA    BBBB    32  C   37000
CCCCC   DDDDD   37  B   40000
```

before enterin in the loop of the loop :) and navigation I was wondering if there is some way to organize the data as I need with some structure that I didn't know and I'haven't found since now.

thx if u have arrived down here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try flatten results using LINQ and then bind results to DataGrid

**EDIT**

I'm pretty new in LINQ to XML but this does the trick as i understand.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile.xml");

            var query = from c in doc.Root.Descendants("candidate")
                        let cat = c.Element("cat")
                        select new
                        {
                            FirstName = c.Element("firstName").Value,
                            LastName = c.Element("lastName").Value,
                            Age = c.Element("age").Value,
                            Salary = c.Element("salaryoff").Value,
                            Exp = c.Element("exp").Value,
                            Award = cat.Element("award").Value,
                            Hst = cat.Element("hst").Value,
                            Previous = cat.Element("previous").Value,
                            Flex = cat.Element("flex").Value,
                            Travel = cat.Element("travel").Value,
                        };
            dgv.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I've been too optimistic. I thougt LINQ was more easy. any suggest anyone ? In the meantim I'm trying to charge all to the xml in a dataset and treat it as a normal db. BTw i'm still open to suggest and thx again to everyone.

Comment: I'll try. in the meantime I had fun searching and trying

Comment: it works exactly in the way I was looking for! thx @Guru-Stron